# ionic2 - unable to retrieve/display data using navcontroller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am unable to display the data I get from `NavParams`. I use `console.log()` and check that I did get the data I wanted but unable to display in the new page.

I think I might had make some mistake during the passing of data, but not sure what did I do wrong.

**first.ts**

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocationsProvider } from '../../providers/locations/locations';

...

    constructor(
        public locations: LocationsProvider,
        public viewCtrl: ViewController,
        public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
        public http: Http,
        public navParams: NavParams,
    ) { }

    newEntry(param){
        this.navCtrl.push('SecondPage',param);
    }

    openActSheetjob_Type(){
        let actionsheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
            title:"Type",
            buttons:[
                {
                    text: 'Hour',
                    handler: () => {
                        let Hourly = "Hourly";  
                        let results =  this.locations.getData(Hourly);
           
                        console.log(results); // data goten

                        this.newEntry({ record: results });   //Suspect mistake
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        actionsheetjob_type.present();
    }
```

**Second.html**

```
<ion-list >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let list of this.results">
        <h2>{{ list.Title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ list.Type }}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Second.Ts**

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log(this.NP.get("record")); //Get NULL
}
```

**locations.ts**

```
//function to get data
data:any;

getData(jobType){
    if (this.data) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('http://localhost/getType.php?Type=' + Type)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            console.log(this.data);
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getData` returns a `Promise` it is asynchronous. `console.log(results)` and `this.newEntry({ record: results })` will run before `results` has a value. And with your code it will not even have the value you think. You can get the value in the `then` function that will be called when the `Promise` resolves.

```
handler: () => {
    let Hourly = "Hourly";  
    this.locations.getData(Hourly)
    .then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        this.newEntry({ record: results });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `this.navCtrl.push('SecondPage',param);` shoud SecondPage import in first.ts file like this should be `import{ SecondPage } from '../second/second'` and its class name gives to `this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage,param);`

Hope this should be help!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not correct. If you use lazy load pages/modules, you must use the string name of the Page (`'SecondPage'` instead of `SecondPage`).

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing what is working in my case, may be it help you.

```
 this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage,{item : xyz});//In First Page
```

and  in constructor of second page us

```
  this.item = params.data.item;// In second page
```